# Why are multiple sockets created by one client

Tags: java, sockets

## Multiple sockets created by one client

The task is to create a server-client communication with sockets. The client is the browser and it requests an html file. The server listens and accepts the connection if a request is made.

I would like to create one thread/client (persisten connection), but can't figure out why are multiple sockets created for one request.

#### Server

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Thread t = new HandleClient(i, socket);
                t.start();
                System.out.println("port:" + socket.getPort() + " is connected to " + socket.getInetAddress());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server(2001);
    }
}
```

#### Example

```
port:50065 is connected to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
port:50066 is connected to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
port:50064 is connected to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Comment: since `accept` is in an infinite loop, given code will accept as many connections as the client(s) open to this code (ignoring memory or similar outage). We cannot see what the client(s) is (are) doing ({some} browser usually also want more information then just the HTML page, e.g. an icon for the page - you should print or log the request to see what is being requested)

Comment: You would have to show client code. It is up to client to reuse established connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html).accept() "...blocks until a connection is made."

When I test your code, the program go no further than up to this accept() method and wait for connection.

Trying to connect in the same loop by your HandleClient thread stated after accept() is impossible.

I don't know what can be the problem that you are receiving any output at all, maybe you have some other working threads, on different programs that are connecting with 2001 port?